# How do I create a file in Python?

Tags: python

I have two lists of strings of the same size. I need to create a single .txt file in which the first appears with a header (example: Countries) then the list items appear like this:

122132, Brazil, 2020

153353, Russia, 2018

Then, the second list has a different header and the same format of content as the example above.

I tried writing this code, but it just prints one of the lists and it prints like a list, for example [122132, Brazil, 2020]

```
with open(file, 'w') as filehandle:
   for listitem in b_bubble:
       filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)

with open(file, 'w') as filehandle:
   for listitem in b_quick:
       filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Adding to an existing file is covered in any tutorial on Python files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code, the first time you open the file you create it if it doesn't exist or overwrite it if it does. the second time you overwrite it because you are opening with the mode "w". if you want to append to the file use "a" for append. see this code

```
with open(file, 'w') as filehandle:
   filehandle.write(', '.join(b_bubble))

with open(file, 'a') as filehandle:
   filehandle.write(', '.join(b_quick))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# let's open a file in write mode, if it exists, we overwrite it's content, if not, create it
with open(file, 'w') as filehandle:
   # add all items from b_bubble
   for listitem in b_bubble:
       filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

```
# well, this time the file exists, OVERWRITE it's content
with open(file, 'w') as filehandle:
   # add all items from b_quick
   for listitem in b_quick:
       filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

What you want is

```
with open(file, 'a') as filehandle:
   # add all items from b_quick
   for listitem in b_quick:
       filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

or better yet! just open the file once

```
with open(file, 'w') as filehandle:
   # add all items from b_bubble
   for listitem in b_bubble:
       filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)

   # add all items from b_quick
   for listitem in b_quick:
       filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```